# which XML library to use for file containing diverse XML tags?

Tags: java, xml, sax

I found many posts describing advantages of different XML parsers, but my question is much specific.

I have variety of tags in my input XML file:

```
 1.<link-protection/>
 2.<undocumented><lcd>
 3. <message>
       *****{with escape characters}</message>
 4.<xyz comment= "**hshhshs">, and more
```

I am current using two approaches:

1. Parsing the XMLs line by line and handling specific cases.
2. Parsing using SAX parser (even here I have to handle many cases)
   I used `startElement(), endElement(), characters()`

In both the cases development time is the same as I had to handle various tags.

I wanted to know is there a more handy XML parser which I can use.

Comment: Have you got a schema?

Comment: Your approach (1) sounds suspiciously like you are writing a home-grown parser. That is definitely NOT the way to do it.

Comment: A lot depends on what you want to do with the information. Do you need to populate a Java object model? Or generate a representation of the data as an HTML page? Or find the maximum value of some attribute? The right approach to parsing will be different in each case.

Comment: I dont have a Java object model. I just want to convert the XML into flat format. For Eg: 
'<A> <B>vaue</B><C>value</C></A>
op: 
A B value
A C value'

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into XStream -https://x-stream.github.io/.
This framework is quite useful and can deal with XML and JSON.

You also can use JAXB (Java Architecture for XML binding).

Here are the steps I would follow:

1. Create a desired XML file.
2. Generate XSD schema file from XML. You can use built-in editor generator or use free online ones - there are plenty of them.
3. Create a series of DTO classes for your XML sections. As an example, *message* XML tag can be presented as Java class Message and each field is annotated for XML parser. If you intend to use JAXB you will need javax.xml annotation. XStream uses its own annotations.
4. Create a code that parses the XML stream either using JAXB (marshalling/unmarshalling), XStream, or any other parser. Make sure to register XSD file generated above with the parser of your choice.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at my [unXml](https://github.com/tajakobsen/unxml)-library. It picks out XPaths from an XML-document, and returns av json object (or a pojo, using the mapper from [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome)).

*Example XML*

```
<root>
  <id>1</id>
  <title>mytitle</title>
</root>
```

*Example ParserCode in Java*

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import com.nerdforge.unxml.Parsing;
import com.nerdforge.unxml.factory.ParsingFactory;
...

public class MyController {
    public ObjectNode getJsonFromXml(String inputXmlString) {
        Parsing parsing = ParsingFactory.getInstance().create();
        Document document = parsing.xml().document(inputXmlString);

        Parser<ObjectNode> parser = parsing.obj("root")
          .attribute("id", "id", parsing.number()) // uses a number parser
          .attribute("title") // both xpath and json-attribute-key is "title"
          .build();

        ObjectNode node = parser.apply(document);
        return node;
    }
}
```

*Resulting Json in ObjectNode*

```
{
  "id":1,
  "title":"mytitle"
}
```